# Ajax can not responded with Entity framework linq

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, linq

In this code the AJAX can not responded. If it doesn't run the code "where r.Email == lsEmail && r.Password == lsPassword" , the AJAX is running successfully.

If add the code "where r.Email == lsEmail && r.Password == lsPassword", the AJAX ".done(function(data)..)" can not accept any success message.

The problem should be in LINQ Where,It's very weird. Does AJAX not work with LINQ? or It,s Microsoft bug?

```js
$('#login-submit').click(function() {
  var lsEmail = $("#email").val().trim();
  var lsPassword = $("#password").val().trim();

  if (lsEmail == "") {
    alert("Email Cannot be blank!");
    return false;
  }

  if (lsPassword == "") {
    alert("Email Cannot be blank!");
    return false;
  }

  var data = {
    lsEmail: lsEmail,
    lsPassword: lsPassword
  };

  var url = "/Home/ClientLogin";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (data == "1") {
      window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
    } else if (data == "2") {
      window.location.href = "/Home/Error";
    }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
  });
});
```

```
public ActionResult ClientLogin(string lsEmail, string lsPassword) 
{
  int liNum;
  liNum = 0;

  try 
  {
    var lzClientUser = from r in db.ClientUser
    where r.Email == lsEmail && r.Password == lsPassword
    select r;

    var lzClientUserNum = lzClientUser.ToList();
    liNum = lzClientUserNum.Count();
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\nErrMsg：{0}\n", ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }

  // Login Success
  if (liNum > 0) 
  {
    Session["LoginEMail"] = lsEmail;
    return Content("1");
  } 
  else 
  {
    return Content("2");
  }
}
```

Comment: I realise English may not be your first language here, but it's very hard to understand what you're asking. Could you please try and edit the question so that the problem is clearer.

Comment: Are you getting any error or response in browser console > network tab?

Comment: above code  "$.ajax({.fail(  alert(jqXHR.status);  alert(textStatus);  alert(errorThrown);});" had been triggered，but the error show null.
not only the entity framework linq 'select' have the error. but also the entity framework linq 'update,insert' without using "try catch" also have this error~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding your action result in ajax response,you need to return json result instead of content result.